# Using overloaded method in parent class

Tags: python, inheritance, polymorphism

Consider the following code:

```
class iterative_solver:

   def stop_condition(self):
   #To be specified in the child classes

   def solver(self):
      while stop_condition:                   #Error
         print("In the cycle")

class specific_solver(iterative_solver):

   def stop_condition(self,num):
      return num>0
```

When I define the method `stop_condition` I don't know yet what arguments it might take, I leave the specific implementation of the method in the child class `specific_solver`.

How can I use inside a parent class, a method that is specified in a child class, for which I don't know the arguments yet?

Comment: How is the `solver` method supposed to work? There is nothing in it, that could change the outcome of the condition.

Comment: You need to define an  interface for the `stop_condition()` and use it in the `solver()` method. It possible to make it fairly generic by using variable length `*args` and *kwargs` arguments.

Comment: Do you have a specific way of doing this, that differs from the answer that was already given? I'm learning Python and OOP programming, so I'm not experienced at all

Comment: Maybe a more practical example for what you want to do would yield other answers. Currently, your question is quite abstract.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Use `*args` and `**kwargs` to allow passing of arbitrary arguments and keyword arguments.

### Example

```
class IterativeSolver(object):

   def stop_condition(self):
       raise NotImplementedError # Use this to indicate that subclass must override the method.

   def solver(self, *args, **kwargs):
      while stop_condition(*args, **kwargs):
         print("In the cycle")

class SpecificSolver(IterativeSolver):

   def stop_condition(self, num):
      return num>0

num = 1
SpecificSolver.solver(num)
```

Comment: Thank you, I got the idea.
However, there are a couple of issues:
(1) the code doesn't run, can you please post a functioning version?
(2) suppose I now have `stop_condition1` and `stop_condition2`, that children classes can override and that I want to use in `solver`. Is there a nice way to differentiate between which parts of `*args` go into which `stop_condition` (1 or 2) ? I think that putting every input into the `solver` method makes things a but messier

Thank you again :)